# Can not make opencv3 run on Xcode with c++ macOs big sur

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I am trying to set up an Xcode c++ project with opencv3, and I set up:

- header search paths: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv@3/3.4.12_3/include
- library search paths: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv@3/3.4.12_3/lib
- other linker flags: the result from pkg-config --cflags --libs /usr/local/Cellar/opencv@3/3.4.12_3/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
  But when I import opencv in c++ code, it just doesn't find the opencv.hpp file. I imported it like this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

And i can see it in the /usr/local/Cellar/opencv@3/3.4.12_3/include/opencv2 folder. I would appreciate any help..

Answer (score 0):

If this is a not a library provided by the system (it's not I think), you should bundle it with your project by adding it to the **Embedded Binaries** section of your target's Build Phase. This way, your application, once compiled, will contain that library in its **Frameworks** folder.

If you don't do that, your compiled application won't run correctly because it will try to use a library that is not present on the computer of your user (so it will probably crash at runtime).

Finally the **header search path** will change accordingly and you should also ensure that this setting is correctly set :

```
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) @executable_path/../Frameworks.
```